# Como saber se um registro foi adicionado ao banco de dados?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Olá, eu estou trabalhando em um sistema de alertas, quando um dado maior que o normal é cadastrado no banco de dados um alerta tem que aparecer na página em que o usuário estiver navegando. O problema é que eu não sei como checar se um elemento foi adicionado ao banco.

Estou pegando meus dados automaticamente de uma PCD (estação meteorológica), se algum desses dados passar do limite cadastrado pelo ADM, um alerta será mostrado ao usuário.

Tenho as seguintes tabelas no meu banco:

```
CREATE TABLE PARAMETROS_DE_ALERTAS (
    PRA_ID INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    PRA_VALOR_MAXIMO INTEGER(5) NOT NULL,
    PRA_VALOR_MINIMO INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRA_COR_MINIMA VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    PRA_COR_MAXIMA VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    SEN_ID INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

Está tabela é o parametro para os alertas, onde será cadastrado o minimo e o máximo da medição vinda da PCD para ela ser um alerta.

```
CREATE TABLE MEDICOES (
    MED_ID INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    MED_DADO VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    MED_DATA_HORA_MEDICAO DATETIME NOT NULL,
    API_ID INTEGER,
    SEN_ID INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

Está é a tabela de medições, onde guardará os dados vindos da PCD.

```
CREATE TABLE ALERTAS_CRITICOS (
    ALC_DATA_HORA_ALERTA DATETIME NOT NULL,
    ALC_ID INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ALC_VALOR_MEDICAO FLOAT NOT NULL,
    SEN_ID INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

O sistema deverá adicionar um registro desta tabela caso o dado da medição seja maior ou menor que os parâmetros. Após que este alerta critico seja cadastrado, o sistema deverá mostrar um alerta ao usuário que esteja navegando em qualquer página de meu site.

O problema é que eu não sei como checar se um registro foi adicionado ao banco.

Comment: Que tipo de elemento vc se refere ?

Comment: Uma tabela mesmo, por exemplo, vou pegar meus dados de um PCD (uma estação meteorológica), que irá me mandar dados como o nível da água de um rio, se o nível passar do limite cadastrado pelo ADM, deverá mostrar um alerta ao usuário.

Comment: Bota um exemplo na sua pergunta, esse trecho que define o limite.

Comment: Qual linguagem está usando, na aplicação ?

Comment: PHP para conectar ao banco e ajax para controlar as funções do php.

Comment: Como está recebendo esses dados, pode colocar um trecho do código php?

Comment: Ainda não cheguei na parte de integrar meu projeto ao PCD, por enquanto estou adicionando os registros diretamente por código SQL.

Comment: Então, imagino que terá de fazer uma comparação na hora de inserir no banco do tipo if(x > y || x < z){echo "foi adicionado";} algo assim... è tipo iso que procura? Mas pode fazer fazer consultas sql oara verificar...

Comment: Sim, essa parte irá adicionar um registro de alerta critico ao banco de dados, mas eu gostaria que aparecesse um alerta para o usuário que está navegando em qualquer página de meu site, então imagino que eu teria que usar um método que verificaria se um um registro de alerta critico foi adicionado ao banco. Ou quando o sistema adicionar o alerta critico mandar algo que dispare um listener na páginas que irá mostrar o alerta.

Comment: Tipo, se vai ter um script que vai ficar atualizando as informações do PDC,, ou seja esse script terá de ser executado automaticamente, de tempos em tempos, e no momento que o retorno estiver dentro dos parâmetros ele alerta para qualquer usuário em qualquer página, é isso?

Comment: Isso, um jeito que eu pensei de realizar essa ação foi de criar um script que verificaria se um alerta critico foi adicionado ao banco de dados de tempos em tempos. Acredito que se eu guardar em uma var qual foi o último id inserido à tabela alertas críticos, e verificar de tempos em tempos se o último registro inserido for > à variável que guardei, ai acionaria o alerta. Acha que isso funcionaria?

Comment: Acho que sim, existem vários meios para se atingir o que vc quer. Acho que um diagrama de blocos, pode de ajudar a decidir o melhor momento de fazer a verificação. Ela pode ser no ato da consulta no PDC, na hora de inserir no banco, ou através de consultas periódicas. O mais importante (eu acho) é vc planejar bem esses passos e ir construindo conforme seu objetivo.

Comment: Sim, muito obrigado MagicHat, agora eu tenho mais ou menos a ideia de como irei fazer isso formulado!

Comment: Talvez, isso ajude ou complique, não é minha intenção,complicar.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html

Answer (score 1):

Voce pode usar uma função de banco para dar esse insert. Dentro dessa função voce faz o INSERT necessario e pode dar um SELECT logo em seguida retornar true ou false para a aplicação saber se foi com sucesso.

Comment: Dependendo do sistema que ele está fazendo, uma `trigger` ao inserir dados na tabela que ele quer resolveria.

Answer (score 1):

Nicolas, pelo que entendi da sua necessidade, não exste um método que fará tudo o que você precisa, então vou sugerir aquilo que eu faria na sua situação:

1. Insert do alerta no banco
2. Read em um arquivo json salvo na sua aplicação
3. Geraria um array, ou adicionaria no array já existente de alertas
4. Criar um middleware para toda a sua aplicação que realiza a leitura deste JSON e exibria os alertas no load da página e ou um js na página com um looping infinito que faz essa leitura através da url do json
5. Excluir os alertas (caso faça parte da sua regra) e salvar esse arquivo após edição

As vantagens de usar json são, você pode editar facilmente o conteúdo (utilizando as funções json_encode e json_decode) e a leitura é extremamente rápida, pois não precisa consultar o banco e não é um volume grande de dados.

Answer (score 0):

Precisa criar uma api que acessa o banco e poderá fazer chamada a ela via ajax.
Essa api consulta o banco e trás os dados e no get de seu ajax ao receber o callback dessa chamada poderá implementar o alerta

Comment: Sim, mas existe um método que verifica se um registro foi adicionado ao banco de dados?